# WordPress WooCommerce move post tags to products tags

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

Is there a way (mySQL, Plugin etc) to move all the **post tags** to **product tags**. The junior created 50+ products and tags as posts instead of products. I have successfully moved the posts but I need to move all of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert Post Tags to Product Tags you need to change the taxonomy related to that terms.
You can move all Post Tags to Product Tags with that SQL query:

```
UPDATE `wp_term_taxonomy` 
SET `taxonomy` = 'product_tag' 
WHERE `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'post_tag';
```

You can also use this query with [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) object methods in a custom function that you will run once.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change taxonomy type from "post_tag" to "product_tag in database.